# issue displaying Variations dropdown in custom template using WPeCommerce Plugin 3.8.9.2

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I’m having trouble displaying variations in a custom built template, each time i call the wpsc function `wpsc_have_variation_groups()` within my loop i get the following php error

commerce/wpsc-includes/product-template.php on line 1419 [22-Nov-2012 23:27:39] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function `have_variation_groups()` on a non-object in /home/tofapost/public_html/sandbox/wp/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-includes/product-template.php on line 1419.

`wpsc_have_variation_groups()` is being called inside a WP_Query loop like so;

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'wpsc-product', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

   ... 

<?php if (wpsc_have_variation_groups()) { ?>

<?php } ?> 

    ...

endwhile;
```

Whats strange is other wpsc functions like, wpsc_the_product_id() and wpsc_product_has_stock() work while no functions related to variations do...

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This has already been answered.  The issue with this question is the fact that not all the code is displayed and the wrong type of loop was used. to list the products.

The answer that was used was to manually obtain the variations because the type of loop does not allow for the ID to be used as there was no identifier for the variations that needed to be obtained.  To be able to use the current code it needed to use a different loop so or change it so that the variation is manually obtained.  In this case the variation was manually obtained.

```
global $wpsc_variations;
$wpsc_variations = new wpsc_variations( get_the_ID() );
```

Reference: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73689/issue-displaying-variations-in-custom-template-using-wpec-3-8-9-2

Answer (score 2):

The wpsc_the_product() function sets up a global $wpsc_variations object that the product variation functions use.

I think in order to use wpsc_the_product() you need your query to be the global $wp_query, but you can setup $wpsc_variations yourself after you open your loop:

```
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    global $wpsc_variations;
    $wpsc_variations = new wpsc_variations( get_the_ID() );
```

That hopefully should get all the product variation functions working.

***You can refer to the following location :***

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73689/issue-displaying-variations-in-custom-template-using-wpec-3-8-9-2

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.